# Can a ROC curve be a straight line even if the AUC is not 1.00?

Tags: roc

[image: Straight line ROC curve]

I have a straight-line ROC curve even if the AUC is not 1.00, I do not understand if it is correct or not. Is it possible that the ROC curve is straight?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The point at (1, 0.7) doesn't make much sense - it indicates you've gotten every single Negative case wrongly classified as a Predicted Positive, yet you still haven't classified all the Positives as Predicted Positives. There's no reason to ever do that, it would be strictly better to simply call *everybody* a Predicted Positive. Points at (0,1) and (1,0) should *always* be present in an ROC, since you can always simply classify everybody as positive/negative, yielding 100% sensitivity and 0% specificity, or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you @NuclearHoagie:
I obtained that ROC curve using the following value:
y_true = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
probs = [[0.13048919, 0.50587728, 0.6547212 , 0.07375166, 0.78436374,
       0.1181461 , 0.67823414, 0.95297399, 0.47900621, 0.13780385,
       0.28541804, 0.11840177, 0.01492127]
and using roc_curve from sklearn.metrics, what was my mistake?

Comment: @mirkojh It's not totally wrong, but important to note that the ROC curve with steps isn't a function - there are two TPR values at FPR=1. In practice, you'd never use the worse-TPR model when both have FPR=1. You can also interpolate between the models represented on an ROC curve, which eliminates the stepwise nature.